# Does pithy need to mean terse?

Tags: meaning

Google defines pithy as "(of language or style) terse and vigorously expressive."

However from the meaning of pith with respect to fruits, the word doesn't seem to contain the attribute of being terse. i.e. when describing a sentence or exposition as pithy I would be figuratively saying it contains a lot of pith/meat.

So I'm wondering if being terse or succinct is a connotation of pithy, or is it not necessary. Can a long sentence or exposition that has substance be called pithy?

Comment: Maybe you should also wonder does terse need to mean short?

Comment: Many words, including [*pithy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show%20off), have more than one meaning. Context determines *which* of their meanings are relevant.

Comment: Try me.  Write a sentence that you think is pithy but long, and I'll tell you if I still find it pithy.

Comment: @JasonBassford I know, but for pithy, it seems to me that the meaning with respect to sentences/exposition is a figurative use of the word pithy, which with respect to fruits would just mean that it has a lot of pith.

Comment: A lot of pith for the size of the fruit / a lot of meaning for the number of words.

Comment: With apologies to Albert, A pithy statement should be as terse as can be, but no terser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I'm wondering if being terse or succinct is a connotation of pithy, or is it not necessary. Can a long sentence or exposition that has substance be called pithy?

The OED's entries include (emphasis mine):

> **pithy, *adj.***
> **2a.** Of language or style: full of **concentrated meaning**; conveying meaning forcibly through **brevity of expression**; **concise**, **succinct**; condensed in style; pointed, terse, aphoristic.
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144742#eid29870294)</sub>

Where all the highlighted terms convey a sense of *not using more words than is necessary*. So, while a phrase/sentence described as *pithy* will *often* be a relatively short, I do not believe it has to be. A longer sentence *could* still be described as pithy, provided it is about as short as it can be while still getting its meaning across. Contrast with *wordy*, *verbose*, *long-winded* etc.

---

Etymologically speaking, the "*terse, succinct*" meaning would seem to come (at least indirectly) from the "fruit" related meaning. For ***pith*** the OED has as a "concrete use":

> **I.** Concrete uses.
> **1.** The soft internal tissue of a plant part; esp. a central cylinder of parenchyma in a stem or root. Also: a layer of spongy tissue lining the rind in certain fruits, especially citrus fruits, in which it is white and often bitter-tasting.

with dated citations back to c1150 (and an earlier undated use). For its "abstract" use (as pertains to sentences), it has both:

> **II.** Abstract uses.
> **4.a.** The innermost or central part of a thing; the essential or vital part; the spirit or essence; the core, the nub. Frequently in **pith and marrow**.
>
> **5.b.** Force, power, energy (of words, speech, etc.). In later use chiefly: the quality of conveying meaning **forcibly through brevity of expression**; succinctness, conciseness.
> <sub>First emphasis theirs; second mine</sub>

with dated uses back to around 1425 for sense *4.a.* and 1531 for sense *5.b.*.

There would seem to be a progression from *pith* meaning the *inner/internal tissue* (of a plant), through the *innermost or central part* (the *core* or *essence*) before getting to "core" meaning of a phrase or sentence, by dint of it being *brief*, *concise* or *succinct*.

Comment: It's refreshing to come across a really satisfying answer. Which often means via the OED.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some explanation of its derivation/etymology.

Comment: *esp. a central cylinder of parenchyma in a stem or root.* this give 4.a. in the OED.

Comment: @Greybeard I'm not sure what you mean... are you saying the quoted section is in 4.a. for you (I've just checked, and it's still in I.1. for me), or are you emphasising that the [concrete] meaning of that phrase leads to the [abstract] meaning in 4.a.?

Comment: No. vice versa. The pith is the central matter. 1. leads to 4a.

Answer (score 2):

Though 'pithy' and 'terse' may arguably be considered synonyms, 'terse' means to use few words, while 'pithy' means to use few words expressively.

Comment: @Jim Another way of looking at it is that he’s shown that they are indeed synonyms, but far from identical.

Comment: With @EdwinAshworth’s edits, I’ll retract my DV and delete my comment.

Comment: Citations might help improve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

They may be synonymous in that they both describe speech that is brief and to the point, but one tends to have a *positive* connotation while the other is usually *negative*.

"Pithy" usually describes speech which gets to the point, and is usually used in a positive, complimentary way. It is synonymous with *succinct, concise, significant, meaningful*, and *carefully honed*.

"Terse" usually describes speech which is *abrupt* in a rude way. It is usually used disparagingly and is not complimentary. It is synoymous with *curt, brusque, abrupt* and *blunt*.

To answer your question then, they do not mean exactly the same thing and to describe someone or their speech as "pithy" does not necessarily mean they are rude or *terse*.

I don't claim to know the origins of the word "pithy" and how it relates to its fruity homonym, but as the pith of fruit tends to be sharp-tasting I would suggest that it is this quality of sharpness which underpins both.

Answer (score 0):

Until today, I being 63 years of age always associated a negative implication when an author or speaker used the word "pithy".

The pith of the citrus fruit or pith of a stem, seems to be meaningless or little use.

The pith of a citrus fruit is thrown away, not eaten.  The core of citrus fruit is what is savored and eaten to give wisdom.  A hollow stem or pith may function for the plant, but appears to be empty space and invitation for a parasite to take hold and cause disease.

I come from both biology and medical degree, MD.  I hope I got to the positive pith meaning enough for this audience discussion.

Comment: Hello, 407. My degrees are in chemistry, but I've had to ditch the '_pithy_ strongly connotes  meaninglessness/waste of space in all usages' opinion  in favour of OED's well-researched (to reflect actual usage) '[of language ...]: full of concentrated meaning'. The etymological fallacy needs addressing.